# How to better implement recurrence relations in code?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple days now, I'm still new to Python and more math intensive coding so any help would be appreciated, just point me in the right direction :)

So the question was something like:

> You have a movie pass which is valid for **N** days. You can use it in any way you want except for ***3 consecutive days or more.***
>
> So basically, you can either use your pass on a given day or choose to not, meaning **2 raised to N** total possibilities. The valid ways for claiming the pass are then **2 raised to N - invalidCases**
>
> You have to find the number of valid cases % (10^9+7)

I found a recurrence relation for the invalid cases which looked like

> invalidCases(at_N) = 2^(n-4) + 2*invalidCases(at_N-1) - invalidCases(at_n-4)

So my first impulse was to simply use recursion:

```
def invalidCases(n):
    if(n<3):
        return 0;
    elif(n==3):
        return 1;
    else:
        return 2**(n-4)+ 2*invalidCases(n-1)- invalidCases(n-4)
```

Very inefficient, but my equation seemed correct.
My next attempt, I tried memoization, but I kept running into an error at N=1006.
So I changed the recursion limit.

My present attempt(with memoization and increased recursion limit)

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
T=int(input());
#2**(n-4) + 2*ans(n-1)-ans(n-4)
memo={0:0,1:0,2:0,3:1,4:3,5:8,6:20,7:47} #
def ans(n):
    #complete this function
    if n not in memo:

        memo[n]=(2**(n-4) + 2*ans(n-1)-ans(n-4));



    return memo[n];

modulo = 10**9 + 7;
print((2**n-ans(n))%modulo);
```

Finally, my problem.
I need this code to work for n = 999999.

How do I bring its worst case down to minimum?
Any pointers or tips would be great.

Comment: A general comment:  The trailing semicolons are unnecessary and very unusual in Python.  Just delete them.

Comment: You can do this bottom up instead of top down. And you can do this counting the valids and also keeping track, at day `j` of the number of possibilities having used the pass on day `j`, and the number of possibilities using both days `j` and `j-1`. Work out the first few days by hand. Also, since 10^9+7 is prime you can store your intermediate results mod 10^9+7 without changing your answer.

Comment: @TomKarzes Haha, sorry, I'm jumping to python from C, so automatically put a semicolon after my statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete solution which is based on the observation that a valid solution for three or more days must begin with one of the following:

```
0
10
110
```

where 1 indicates the pass is used on that day, and 0 indicates it is not.

There are valid(n-1) possibilities for the first form, valid(n-2) possibilities for the second form, and valid(n-3) possibilities for the third form.

The recurrence is then:

> valid(n) = valid(n-1) + valid(n-2) + valid(n-3)

The basis cases are valid(0) = 1, valid(1) = 2, and valid(2) = 4.  It is important to note that valid(0) is 1, not zero. That's because there is exactly one solution when n=0, namely, the empty sequence. This is not only mathematically correct, but is also needed for the recurrence to work correctly.

The code does three things to make it run fast:

1. It uses a cache to cache results (memoization), as you had done.
2. It doesn't store the full results, but instead first applies the modulus, greatly reducing the value ranges.
3. It preloads the cache, starting with 0 and going up to the desired value.  This reduces the maximum recursion depth to one.

Here's the code:

```
cache = {}
modulus = 10**9 + 7

def valid(n):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]

    if n == 0:
        v = 1
    elif n == 1:
        v = 2
    elif n == 2:
        v = 4
    else:
        v = valid(n-1) + valid(n-2) + valid(n-3)

    v %= modulus

    cache[n] = v
    return v

def main():
    # Preload the cache
    for n in range(1000000):
        valid(n)

    print(valid(999999))

main()
```

Here's the output:

```
746580045
```

It runs in under 2 seconds on my system.

Update:  Here's a minimal iterative solution, inspired by the approach used by MFisherKDX.  The seed values were constructed in a way that eliminates the need for special-casing (the intial v2 is valid(0)):

```
modulus = 10**9 + 7

def valid(n):
    v0, v1, v2 = 0, 1, 1

    for i in range(n):
        v0, v1, v2 = v1, v2, (v0 + v1 + v2) % modulus

    return v2

print(valid(999999))
```

This solution is probably as fast as you can get.  It discards the intermediate results after using them, which is fine if you're only calling the function once.

Comment: Nice Tom.  You can probably solve that homogeneous recurrence: `V(n) - V(n-1) - V(n-2) - V(n-3) = 0` with initial conditions `v(0)=1, v(1)=2, v(2)=4` to produce a closed form answer.  The characteristic polynomial has 1 real and 2 complex roots.

Comment: Ok, theres another extension to this question, which is to find the answer for 10**18.

Comment: You should be able to set `modulus` to whatever you want and it should work.

Comment: I think the start of your question isn't quite right -- the valid forms are `(empty|1|11)(0|01|011)*` (or `(0|10|110)*(empty|1|11)`) and not `(0|10|110)*` as stated.

Comment: @PaulHankin I clarified the description and the notation.  Those three prefixes were only meant to apply to sequences of three or more days, and they were only meant to be prefixes, not regular expressions.  I removed the `*` from the notation, and clarified the explantion.  The basis cases for 0, 1, or 2 days are not included in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer.  Bottom up solution.  Compare with Tom's answer which is top down and equally valid.  At each day `j` it keeps track of the number of possibilities that use the pass on day `j` as well as the number of possibilities that use the pass on both `j` and `j-1`.

```
def ans(n):

    total = 1
    tcd = 0 #total used at current day
    tcpd = 0 #total used at current and previous day
    m = 1000000007

    for j in range(0, n):

        next_tot = 2*total - tcpd
        next_tcd = total - tcpd
        next_tcpd = tcd - tcpd

        total = next_tot % m

        tcd = next_tcd % m
        tcpd = next_tcpd % m

    return total

print(ans(999999))
```

Result is `746580045` and takes 400ms on my system.

Comment: I added a minimal iterative solution to the end of mine, inspired by your approach but with only one % operation per iteration.  Feel free to improve on it further if you see a way to do so!

Comment: @TomKarzes Nice catch. From 400ms to 300ms. :)

Comment: Thanks.  A closed-form solution sounds very appealing, but my guess is you wouldn't be able to get an exact result from it without jumping through hoops.

Comment: It also occurred to me that if you strengthen the restriction, so that a pass may not be used on two or more consecutive days, then you end up with the standard two-term Fibonacci sequence.  For each additional day that is added to the restriction, you simply add an additional term to the recurrence.